# Where can I find a good ByteArrayMap implementation? (fast with low gc)

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, dictionary

I am looking for a map implementation which uses byte arrays (byte[]) as the map key.

You can perform get operations like that map.get(myByteArray, 0, len);

Google did not help. :(

Comment: You shall implement it yourself, as map's get method just get's a single argument.

Comment: True, it can still be a java.util.Map and provide an extra method, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) . It implements hashcode method in way that generated hash will depend upon the content of ByteBuffer. However you have to make sure that content of these buffer used as key should not change.

Direct from JavaDoc
Because buffer hash codes are content-dependent, it is inadvisable to use buffers as keys in hash maps or similar data structures unless it is known that their contents will not change.

This is one way to do this. Other is to implement your own class which will store byte array and implement hashCode() and equals() method which considers content of this byte array.

Comment: Cool. Any open-source implementation of this you recommend? ByteBuffers as keys won't help me.

Comment: I doubt whether there is any opensource implementation available. Anyway, What is problem in second approach, 'writing your own class'. Its simple and efficient solution as you can manage generation of hashcode for key. Personally I would have preferred this approach.

Comment: You can't really write a `Map` with `byte[]` keys, the way you seem to want to, without breaking the `Map` contract.